# Can the Interfaces and Class used in a Lambda Expression be put in separate files?

Tags: java, file, class, lambda, interface

This may be a bit of a silly question, but I'm newish to Lamda Expressions and programming in General.

After experimenting around with Lambda Expression like so :

```
interface Starter {
    public void start();
}

class Machine {
public void run( Starter s ) {
    System.out.println("Running code....");
    s.start();
 }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Machine mac1 = new Machine();
    mac1.run(() -> System.out.println("Hello World"));
}
```

It made me wonder, if the Interface, and the class (Machine in this case) can be moved into seperate files for this to still work? I tried doing it how I think it would work, but that didn't work, is this possible? and if so how do you do it?

Comment: yes. you can do it.

Comment: It is *extremely* rare for more than one top-level class to be in a single source file. Although the language supports it, it is never done in real work. I've only ever seen it in small ad-hoc pieces of code, e.g. when posting code to online test/challenge sites. So to answer your question: Yes, you can *always* put top-level classes in separate source *files*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the Machine class and Starter interface are visible to your main class, then this is perfectly possible.

My guess is that you moved the Starter interface to another package than the main class, and as you have not included the "public" modifier, it is no longer visible to the main class and will refuse to compile.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correct, than just add a separate class (say `App.class`), that contains `public static void main` method:

```
public interface Starter {

    public void start();

}

public class Machine {

    public void run( Starter s ) {
        System.out.println("Running code....");
        s.start();
    }

}


public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Machine mac1 = new Machine();
        mac1.run(() -> System.out.println("Hello World"));
    }

}
```